# Is there a way to do this with a LINQ Query?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-3.0, linq-to-entities

<< Obfuscated >>

In my repository I declare `IQueryable<Foo> foos` and `ConfigEntities db = new ConfigEntities()`  I then query the db with the linq query

```
foos = from f in _db.Foos
       select f;
```

Each Foo has an individual collection of `EntityCollection<Bar> bars` that is automagically populated by the Entity Framework.

I want to iterate over the foos collection *and* over the bars collections in each Foo, and modify the bars collection based on the date, something like:

```
from foo in foos
    (from bar in foo.bars
         where bar.Date < someDate && bar.Date >= someOtherDate
         select bar)
     select foo
```

So I get back *all* of the foos with *a subset* of the original bars.  I'm not sure how, but I think I want to do a select within a select or something of that sort.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hm, this seems to be a bit contra-relativistic to me: how can entries in a collection which has been existing for certain amount of time have an entry with value of `DateTime.Now`? Don't you rather want to select entries which have value of their property `Date` in certain range? I (mis)understood, that you just want to set property `Date` to `DateTime.Now`, don't you?

Comment: My apologies - the use of `DateTime.Now` was strictly for illustration purposes.  In reality, I am indeed checking for a date in a certain range.  I shall edit to reflect same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from foo in foos
from bar in foo.bars
where bar.Date == DateTime.Now
select new { foo, bar }
```

or (edited, considering you don't have the corresponding constructor for `Foo`)

```
from foo in foos
select new
{
  Foo = foo, 
  Bars = from bar in foo.bars
         where bar.Date == DateTime.Now
         select bar
}
```

This will give a collection of “tuples”, where each will contain the original `Foo` (with all the `Bar`s) and also a collection of the `Bar`s you want.

Comment: for your first example - wont' that create a new foo and bar objects for every time there is a foo with a matching bar? ie foo1 has array of bars = bar1, bar2, bar3 that match the `where` clause - doesn't Ex1 return fooA and BarA, fooB and BarB, FooC and BarC?  It looks to me like *every time* the bar matches it creates a new foo as well

Comment: it looks like you're probably onto something with Example2 - I will definitely check that out on Monday !

Comment: @ScottSEA: No, the first query doesn't create any Foos or Bars, it returns every matching Bar along with the corresponding Foo.

Comment: I don't have a constructor for Example 2 - which feels very much like what I'm looking for.  The problem is that the `EntityCollection <Bar> bars` collection is created dynamically by the Entity Framework - the `select bar` line returns an IQueryable<T>, not an EntityCollection<T> I am truly stumped here.